# How to convert an integer column to varchar in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I have copied the results from SQL Server except the last column (`expected_rn_af`) which was added later.

How can I convert column `rn_af` to `expected_rn_af` using update statement in SQL Server?

Comment: Are 1 through 9 the only supported values?  Do you have a look up table, for converting rn_af to Expected_Rn_af?  Do you have an update statement, even if it does not work?

Comment: are you wanting to CREATE a new column with the new value in SQL Server, or are you wanting to REPLACE the current value with the updated value?  also, what's the current structure of the data?

Comment: In addition to other answers below you have options like this: `substring('ABCDEFGHI', rn_af, 1)`

Comment: @shawnt00.. Thank you, It worked. update #temp
set rn_af = substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', cast(rn_af as int), 1)

Answer (score 4):

Add 64+rn_af within char()

```
Update YourTable
   Set Expected_Rn_af = char(64+rn_af)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a case statement...

```
...
case 
   when rn_af = 1 then 'A' 
   when rn_af = 2 then 'B'
   ...
end as expected_rn_af
```